# How can i retrieve the list of ERC20 tokens bridged to other evm chains?

Tags: tokens, layer-2, bridge

Is there is a way (preferably not relying on an external API) to retrieve a list of tokens bridged to L2 or other EVM chains corresponding to a token on the Ethereum mainnet.

I thought of parsing bridge contract transactions but it seems quite complex to implement. Is there an easier way ?

Thanks for any help!